# Pass the index of a dataframe into a function

Tags: python, pandas

How do you pass an index to a function? It seems to work fine when assigning it to a column, but not when passing it to an external function:

```
data=[{
    'directors': 'Ertil Altanaj',
    'director_score': 0.4,
}, {
    'directors': 'Erbil Altanaj',
    'director_score': 1,
}, {
    'directors': 'Richard Klemann',
    'director_score': 1,
}]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['director_score_match'] = df.director_score >= 0.90


def other_is_true(row): # also, any way to convert this into a lambda?
    index=row.index
    field='director_score_match'
    l = df[field].tolist()
    del l[index]
    return any(l)

df['director_score_other_match'] = df.apply(other_is_true)


>>> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not RangeIndex
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. An explanation of what you’re trying to do would also be good, as it’s currently quite unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But two things stick out from your code:

- If you want to apply it row-wise, use `axis=1`
- A row does not have an index, it has a name

Corrected:

```
def other_is_true(row):
    index=row.name # here
    field='director_score_match'
    l = df[field].tolist()
    del l[index]
    return any(l)

df['director_score_other_match'] = df.apply(other_is_true, axis=1) # and here
```

Since `other_is_true` is a multi-statements function, you can't convert it to a lambda. Perhaps elaborate on what you do so we can help you rewrite the function.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. I'm trying to see if there are other rows that evaluate to True (that's why I'm deleting the list index and then returning `any`).